# Extract top 10% of column values in Excel and place in another column

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel spreadsheets with values in one column. What i need is a VBA code that will identify top 10% of column values, and place them in a adjacent column.

Comment: Is your data formatted as a `table`?

Comment: It's not a table, it's a column of values. All i want is a code that selects the top 10% of the values in that column and insert them somewhere else

Comment: what do you mean by top ten percent of the values? Do you mean if there were 10 rows of data that you'd want the code to select the first row value and insert it somewhere else? (since 10% of 10 = 1)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why not ignore VBA and use the percentile function to create a true false column and filter on that.

EG. Is the Value in B2 in the top 10% of values in Column B?

```
=B2>=PERCENTILE($B$2:$B$17,0.90)
```