# select lowest percentage values

Tags: vba, excel, plot

With a set of data that has for each user an age and a score, I would like to select and plot the lowest 15% of the scores for each age.

Is there a way to simply take out the lowest 15% of scores for each age? This would be preferably in an automated way (don't want to have to repeat process for all 100 ages)

[image]

I have tried the conditional formatting but then I would have to manually select what data to keep. I suspect it is a complicated if function that hopefully I wont have to rewrite for each age.

I've created a column that ranks the scores with respect to the other of that age:

```
RANK(B4,$B$4:$B$426,1)
```

Then in a new column convert that to a percentage of the total number of entries for that age:

```
(E4/COUNT($E$4:$E$426))*100
```

Then an IF statement where it copies the score only if it is in the bottom 15% of scores;

```
IF(F4<15,B4,"-")
```

This process is long and messy doesn't seem logical to repeat it 100 times so how to I automate it?

Comment: Please share what you have tried and where you are stuck.

Comment: @Tiffany: take a look at [SO: Extract top 10% of column values in Excel and place in another column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13236127/extract-top-10-of-column-values-in-excel-and-place-in-another-column)

Comment: @tiffany: also, take a look at [Get the top 10 percent : SQL Select « Access « VBA / Excel / Access / Word](http://www.java2s.com/Code/VBA-Excel-Access-Word/Access/Getthetop10percent.htm) - you can change the connection to your MS Excel worksheet, and use SQL to get the percentage you want!

Comment: @OurManinBananas thank you! unfortunated still havent found a way of making it do the same thing for each age, but thats okay